# Swagger | Springboot 3.2 | The provided definition does not specify a valid version field

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springdoc-openapi-ui, spring-boot-3

[swagger-ui/index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ4vQ.png)

How to fix the error of:
The provided definition does not specify a valid version field after implementing Swagger under Spring Boot 3.2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        final Collection<HttpMessageConverter<?>> myConverters = new ArrayList<>();

        final Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.serializerByType(ObjectId.class, new ToStringSerializer());

        final HttpMessageConverter<Object> converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build());
        myConverters.add(converter);
        myConverters.addAll(converters);

        converters.clear();
        converters.addAll(myConverters);
    }
```

```
springdoc:
  writer-with-default-pretty-printer: true
  swagger-ui:
    display-request-duration: true
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
  api-docs:
    version: openapi_3_1
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, just add the folling parameter in the openapi section !

Then it works fine!

[screenshot of application.yml with openapi conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1jtJ.png)

[screenshot of Swagger fixed exposed with entrypoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duxyv.png)